# 05 Mazda 6i battery drain headlights and turn signals not working

Tags: mazda, turn-signal, mazda-6

Started with trans problems 2 alternators later fixed. Starter went bad replaced it window fuse kept blowing fixed it now head lights and turn signals not working all fuses in box and panel are good. Also battery is drained after 6 hours. Anyone have suggestions on where to start?  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Typical troubleshooting would say to keep pulling fuses (one at a time) until you find your power drain. That should tell you where to start looking.